# Codename One InputStream and OutputStream

Tags: codenameone

I'm a bit confused about `Storage` and `FileSystemStorage`. I wrote the following methods, but I'm sure that they don't work as expected, because `.contains("/")` is not enough to distinguish if we are using `Storage` or `FileSystemStorage`.

Could you please help me to fix them? Thank you

```
/**
     * Get an InputStream for the given sourceFile, it automatically chooses
     * FileSystem API or Storage API
     *
     * @param sourceFile
     * @return
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static InputStream getInputStream(String sourceFile) throws IOException {
        if (sourceFile.contains("/")) {
            return FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(sourceFile);
        } else {
            // Storage is a flat file system
            return Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(sourceFile);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get an OutputStream for the given sourceFile, it automatically chooses
     * FileSystem API or Storage API
     *
     * @param destFile
     * @return
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static OutputStream getOutputStream(String destFile) throws IOException {
        if (destFile.contains("/")) {
            return FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(destFile);
        } else {
            // Storage is a flat file system
            return Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream(destFile);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they should be pretty good. In theory storage would allow you to use `/` as part of the file name but honestly it isn't something we've tested and I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do.

`FileSystemStorage` requires an absolute path and as such will always include a slash character. So this should work fine. Technically a `FileSystemStorage` path should start with `file://` but APIs often work without it to make native code integration easier so that's not a great way to distinguish the API.